# What's the best way to share photos with a client?

Tags: file-management, file-sharing

I found [some answers here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18968/whats-the-easiest-way-to-deliver-raw-images-online-to-a-client), but they seem a bit dated (thus I'd argue this isn't a duplicate). Currently, I create a private gallery on my website where I post the finished images, but the website downgrades them to about 90% resolution, and only provides the option to download a low-res sample. The thing I like about the site is that the customer can purchase prints directly from it if they so choose.

I then send the full-res finished images in a USB stick to the customer. I was using Google Drive or Dropbox for a while, but my Google Drive started to fill up and buying more storage seems like a temporary fix until I need more storage again.

So what do you use to share finished images with clients? How about for your own images so that you can easily access them from anywhere and show/share?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to deliver RAW images online to a client?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18968/whats-the-easiest-way-to-deliver-raw-images-online-to-a-client)

Comment: Think the way to handle dated questions/answers is to update them.

Comment: "*I was using Google Drive or Dropbox for a while, but my Google Drive started to fill up and buying more storage seems like a temporary fix until I need more storage again.*". You don't need to keep your customers' files there forever. Give them 15 days to download them and then remove them. This way you don't need cloud storage bigger than what you sell in 15 days.

Answer (score 6):

DropBox is free unless you want/need a larger storage allowance, which will cost you.  (https://www.dropbox.com/buy?_tk=individual_hero_button)

PixieSet is free, though the website takes a 15% commission fee.
(https://pixieset.com/upgrade/)

Comment: I've found WeTransfer to be useful too - you can send up to 2 GB for free

Answer (score 2):

I have found firefox send as a quick fix for one time file sharing option.
it has 1 gb per link limit and the file is off-internet after 24 hours or a customisable number of downloads , whichever occurs first. so this fixes sharing with client I hope.

for own viewing and showing, I think using plans of the editing software you use can be good. Creative cloud in Lightroom  gives 1TB space viewable across all devices. which is the max I ever came across and editing is also such a streamlined experience.

if not that, apple time machine backs up content, but since I am not a user, I don't know about sharing and accessibility from multiple devices.

a quite radical idea is using GitHub but it will be only public repositories for free. payment is there for making private folders but the good point of unlimited space is still there.

hope it helps.

Comment: I'll have to look into Creative Cloud. I've been avoiding paying for cloud storage as much as I can, but I'm getting to the point that I might have to. Thanks!

Comment: Alexandra's answer has one downside of knowing how to handle web servers and the data transfer costs us as many times the client downloads content. 
firefox send does the exact I same thing as Alexandra does so much faster. and an open source reputed community if promises to delete files permanently after 24 hours or the specified number of downloads, I can trust them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't often share files, as I like to have control over how my work gets printed. Also, I think there are a lot of risks regarding files on shared or Cloud servers. Thus, when I do share a file with a client, I upload them to my own html website on my own server and post a text page with only the links that give access to the (full-size) jpegs for download. (As I control the website including code and folders, I also control what size of image can be downloaded.)

This page is not accessible via the menu on my website; I just e-mail the client a link and also a deadline after which the images will be removed from my server. So, they get two to four weeks to download the files, and then the files are removed from my website. This helps ensure both that I don't permanently use a huge amount of space, and also reduces the likelihood anyone will stumble across what I consider to be images that belong to the client (and sometimes the rights still belong to me) but are not in the public domain.

Comment: It's worth using robots.txt to deny access to the download folder, as otherwise if you or your client use webmail the provider might index the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [zippyfiles.co](https://zippyfiles.co) to send large files upto 10Gb and its free. i think it allows you to password the files too